# errors cause white page and no traces in logs

Tags: php, debugging, logging

## The Issue :

Errors in a php script cause white pages, no traces are found in the logs nor anywhere

## The Story (debug steps) :

I'm supposed to debug an outdated project, but it seems accessing any page would cause a blank/white page, no errors issued, and nothing in the apache error logs.

Most of the code I reviewed line by line can never cause such an issue (no syntax errors and no invalid variables or such).

I've removed '@' (used to disallow showing errors/debug info if an issue occurs to the function call) before function calls, installed an error_handler, checked if .htaccess is disallowing the view of the errors, enabled error reporting in both my php code and php.ini, yet nothing appears in the Apache nor PHP error logs.

## The Solution :

Can be Found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6254144/437912).

Best Regards !

Comment: Did you check your mysql connectivity/log, if that's included in your app?

Comment: @chelmertz nein, but it seems everything else is working,let me check =P

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using an interactive debugger?

Comment: Are you sure your script always outputs something? When you say "white page", are you referring to the rendered by the browser or is the source view also blank? How did you debug "line by line?" I've seen cases where when something failed (or, in other cases, succeeded), the script didn't print anything.

Comment: @all checked the mysql log still nothing,plues i am using xdebugger and still no error to output,the script MUST output, i even tried echo but it doesn't work O_O

Comment: ok guys,i've found that php doesn't output an error for the files that have been "required" which is weird,now when i access to the required file directly it reproduces an error;call-time-pass-reference-has-been-deprecated, i've removed '&' from he function arguments and now there is no white page, the funny thing is the code no longer working as its supposed to be i'll have to rewrite it i guess,thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution :

The issue was caused by an outdated OpenID api library, still the reason why the script did not output errors nor log them is still unknown, I highly suspect deprecated functions and such.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you start by backing up the page.  Making a new one and put a basic `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` and see how you go.

Then break it by changing it to `<?php ecKo "Hello world"; ?>` and see what happens.  Start small, work your way up.

Comment: as i said in my comment to cuismar9, this helped me, thank you,but still, why doesn't php output an error ?

Comment: you say you have "enabled error reporting"  have you set error_reporting(-1) -  Display all PHP errors?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new blank page with nothing in it but an echo? Then you can build the page up slowly and see if you can find a problem.

Actually I've also had this problem when there's an error in the htaccess file, try removing that

Comment: thanks alot chief, this helped me determine exactly where in my class the error resides =],now i'll have to do it more on the other functions and see which exactly the function causing this,thank you for the idea though =D,but why doesn't php output an error?